# SQL Server, DATEDIFF error, formatting of date fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I have an error on my datediff statement.  Comment out the datediff & the 'Nothing clicked' bit works fine.  I think it's related to the format of the date variables.

error message..

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Nothing clicked' to data type int.

```
select

case 
when stVs.DateLastAction is null then 'Nothing clicked'
else DATEDIFF(MI,StVs.DateSessionStarted,stVs.DateLastAction)
end as test

From Stats_VisitorSessions StVs
```

Comment: [Please don't use lazy shorthand like `MI` - just spell out `MINUTE`, it's not that hard](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
select
case 
when stVs.DateLastAction is null then 'Nothing clicked'
else CONVERT(varchar(30),DATEDIFF(MI,StVs.DateSessionStarted,stVs.DateLastAction))
--   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                        ^
end as test

From Stats_VisitorSessions StVs
```

TSQL is having a hard time resolving if the `test` result set column is numeric or string.

A `CASE` expression can only return one datatype.  It cannot return both a numeric and string data type. In the OP's case, it is deciding on a numeric data type, and then it processes more rows, and finds that it needs to be a string, and it fails.  See [Data type precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx).

Comment: `A CASE expression can only return one datatype.` Well, you can do it with certain types - the types returned don't have to be the same, they just have to be compatible and eligible for implicit conversion. Order matters, too. e.g. `SELECT CASE WHEN 1 <> 1 THEN 'help' ELSE  GETDATE() END;` vs. `SELECT CASE WHEN 1 <> 1 THEN GETDATE() ELSE 'help' END;`

Answer (score 3):

The problem here are different datatypes in the `CASE` expression. Add a `CAST` and everything should work:

```
select

case 
when stVs.DateLastAction is null then 'Nothing clicked'
else CAST(DATEDIFF(MI,StVs.DateSessionStarted,stVs.DateLastAction) AS varchar)
end as test

From Stats_VisitorSessions StVs
```

Another option would be to return `NULL` instead of the message and let the application handle that case.